# Fatal Error Class file for 'DOMDocument' cannot be found

Tags: php, apache, prado

We are using one application with httpd server. For performance, I moved httpd from prefork.c to worker.c, then i restart httpd.

now i am getting following error .

```
Fatal Error

Class file for 'DOMDocument' cannot be found.

Debug Backtrace


1  -- PradoBase::autoload('DOMDocument')

2 TXmlDocument.php:385 -- spl_autoload_call('DOMDocument')

3 TXmlDocument.php:371 -- TXmlDocument->loadFromString('  <parameters>   <parameter id="siteTitle" value=&q...')

4 TParameterModule.php:75 -- TXmlDocument->loadFromFile('/var/www/html/swp_branches/protected/settings.xml')

5 TApplication.php:909 -- TParameterModule->init(TXmlElement)

6 TApplication.php:956 -- TApplication->applyConfiguration(TApplicationConfiguration, false

7 TApplication.php:370 -- TApplication->initApplication()

8 index.php:56 -- TApplication->run()
```

Comment: DOMDocument is a built-in class, it won't need autoloading. Why are you trying to autoload it?

Comment: I guess the autoloader is being called because the Dom extension is not installed

Comment: Ahh, WayneC is on to something. Srinivas, what PHP version are you running?

Comment: i am using PHP 5.3.8 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2011 17:34:42)

Comment: i installed php-xml also

Comment: i enabled  Dom extension also ,restarted httpd .still not working

Comment: @SrinivasNallapati clear all caches...

Comment: just a hunch but maybe prado uses its own namespace so you'd need to call `$doc = new \DomDocument();` ?

Comment: i clear all cache of firefox .still same problem

Comment: when i moved from worker.c to prefork.c in httpd . Then it is working fine with out error .but i need module worker.c .Please help me .